forwardRef with Rollup config "preserveModules: true" breaks the build
Context
I'm working on an npm package with Vite and React. Here you can see my vite.config.mts :
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), dts({ include: ['src'] })],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.ts'),
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
      fileName: 'index',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react/jsx-runtime', 'downshift', '@heroicons/react', 'next/image'],
      output: {
        preserveModules: true,
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    include: ['**/?(*.)test.ts?(x)'],
  },
});

The problem:
I have a storybook app to display all the components generated from this package, in the same repo, but if there's at least one component with forwardRef in it, it outputs the following error message on every component:
ReferenceError: p is not defined
    at http://localhost:6006/@fs/.../package_name/dist/index.mjs:7:2

My discoveries:

This only happens if I use preserveModules: true
The error message above points to an empty line but it surely refers to a faulty .mjs output file that uses the same letter, that .mjs file always uses forwardRef
Only importing forwardRef or using it to wrap my component, doens't trigger the error. It only appears if I add it to its' props, even if I don't use it. An example of what I mean:

This is ok
const Component = forwardRef<HTMLElement, Props>(({ ...props }) => <div />)

This is not ok
const Component = forwardRef<HTMLElement, Props>(({ ...props }, ref) => <div />)


In the .mjs output, there's only one difference, as you can see from the diff below. The output on the left works fine, the one on the right breaks everything



Manually editing the resulting .mjs in node_modules/ to reset that diff doesn't change anything, even if editing the styling has a visible effect. This last thing might be just due to my misunderstanding of how Storybook caches stuff but it felt relevant.

Thanks in advance for any help!
